# Transaction timeout when publishing multiple pages

Tags: publishing, database

When I'm publishing a small amount of pages in my Tridion 2011 SP1 dev environment, I do not have any problem, but when I start publishing around 15 pages simultaneously, I receive the following error. Any thoughts what the issue can be? I already checked my statistics, but that wasn't the issue. Am I running into a deadlock?

```
The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction.
Transaction Timeout


Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService
Errorcode: 0
User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

StackTrace Information Details:
   at System.Transactions.TransactionState.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(InternalTransaction tx, IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification, Transaction atomicTransaction)
   at System.Transactions.Transaction.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction tx)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.ActivateConnection(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.GetConnection()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.GetStoredProcedureCommand(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.Execute(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.IdentifiableObjectDataMapper.Read(TcmUri id, StoredProcedureInvocation spInvocation)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.IdentifiableObjectDataMapper.Tridion.ContentManager.Data.IIdentifiableObjectDataMapper.Read(TcmUri id)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetDataObject(TcmUri id)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Load(LoadFlags flags, Boolean forceReload)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PublishEngine.InternalCreatePublishTransactions(IEnumerable`1 items, PublishInstructionBase instruction, IEnumerable`1 targets, Nullable`1 priority)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PublishEngine.CreatePublishTransactions(IEnumerable`1 items, PublishInstructionBase instruction, IEnumerable`1 targets, Nullable`1 priority)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PublishEngine.Publish(IEnumerable`1 items, PublishInstruction publishInstruction, IEnumerable`1 targetTypes)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.Publish(IEnumerable`1 ids, PublishInstructionData publishInstruction, IEnumerable`1 targets, Nullable`1 priority, ReadOptions readOptions)
   at SyncInvokePublish(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.TransactionSupportInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Comment: Are your templates heavy in that they take upwards of a minute to resolve the layout of the page?  I think if you posted some details about the content of the publishing / template code that would help get a suitable answer.

Comment: templates are DD4T (v1.25) with linklevel 2. The component schemas are not that complex.

Comment: Could the issue be related to the number of template render threads you have on the CM box?

Comment: There are a couple of Hotfixes related to publishing timeouts & deadlocks, especially when containing Taxonomy. Are you up to date with Hotfixes? Can you increase the logging level and look at the log files?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue recently, and it turned out to be memory usage of my SQL server 2012 and Windows 2012 and Tridion 2013 "all-in-one-box". Upping the RAM from 2 to 3 GB "fixed" it - at least I didn't get any errors anymore.

I'd recommend that you look into how much memory you're using and how publishing impacts that usage.

Answer (score 4):

We are up to date with hotfixes. The issue is now resolved. We did three things, not sure which one solved it (from most likely to unlikely):

1. Removed a non-reachable server from the queue-consumers table by setting is_online to 0
2. Increased the database timeout for core services from 30 to 60 seconds
3. Rebooted the server

Answer (score 1):

Apply the **SDL Tridion SP1 Hotfix Rollup # 2**.

Alternatively, specific to your error, apply following hotfixes at least and then retry:

- CD_2011.1.1.84879 - Cumulative hotfix
- CD_2011.1.1.84845 - Cumulative hotfix
- CD_2011.1.1.83467 - Cumulative hotfix

These are available at the [SDL Tridion World Site](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2011_SP1_1/index.aspx) (require login)

Hopefully, this should resolve your issue.

**NOTE:**

In any case, you must already have SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 Hotfix Rollup # 1 applied on your server.